# How to create a public custom WordPress widget

Tags: wordpress, widget

I want to create a widget for WordPress that anybody can use (for free) which contains some entertaining content (like a gadget for iGoogle in earlier times).
What I did not find out:

- Can a (custom) widget be public/listed, so everybody using WordPress can see and use it?
- Or do I need to create a plugin in order for other WordPress users to see and use it?
- Since I want to let the users decide, where to put this additional content, how can I achieve this? (i.e. integrate this widget behaviour into a WordPress plugin?)

The basic idea is that we have some interesting content, we want to spread on WordPress for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you wether you want to create you widget through you theme (eg: via functions.php) or via a plugin. If you would like everyone to use it independently from a theme, then the best idea would be to do it through a plugin.

Here is a simple tutorial that explains the pieces of code you need to include either in your theme or in a new plugin to create a Widget accessible via the WordPress's widgets panel: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget

Comment: Thank you very much: I assume if I want to have to biggest reach/audience/distribution for my widget, creating a plugin would be the better option since a theme is more likely to be used than a plugin, correct?

Comment: Yes @SimonFerndriger, I think so. Hope it helped